# Meta regresssion with Standardized Mean Difference

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression, standardized-mean-difference

I am doing a meta-analysis of studies comparing A and B. As some studies used different scales (measurement techniques), we have decided to pool all studies and used standardized mean difference (SMD). We would like to do a meta-regression, incorporating some covariates to analyze the difference. I am using "metafor" package in R to do that, but "metafor" does not allow to do a meta-regression with SMD? Is there any specific reason? I can do manually the calculation of SMD then analyze it as raw mean difference? Is that a valid approach?

Comment: `metafor` can do meta-regression with any effect size measure, including SMDs.